# how to access items in a python dictionary by their name

Tags: python, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a shopping cart with the code below

`

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE=300 
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE =True
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
    product_id =str(product.id)
    request.session[product_id] ={"product_name":str(product.title),"price":str(product.price),"quantity":quantity}
    items =request.session.items()
    print(items) 
    return render(request, 'cart/display_cart.html', {"products":request.session})`
```

**Scenario one**
when I pass items to my view like this=> `return render(request, 'cart/display_cart.html', {"products":items})` and loop over it in the template using `{% for item in products %}{{ item.product_name }} {% endfor %}` nothing shows. but when I print it=> print(items) I get `dict_items([('7', {'product_name': 'Tomatoe', 'price': '15.00', 'quantity': '3'})])` in my console. how can i print the items in my template

**Scenario 2**
when I pass request.session like this => return render(request, 'cart/display_cart.html', {"products":request.session}) and I do

```
 {% for key, value in products.items %}
         <li><a href="{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

in my template I get 
{'product_name': 'Tomatoe', 'price': '20.00', 'quantity': '1'}.  how can I display the items in my template using product_name instead of key? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` is a nested `dict`

Use:

```
{% for k, item in products.items %}
    {{ item.product_name }}
{% endfor %}
```